# Weekday symbol in MO TU WE ... format?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, weekday

I need weekday symbol in `MO TU WE TH FR SA SU`

I am using `setDateFormat:@"EEEEE"];` with `shortWeekdaySymbols`

But it only return Sun Mon etc. Let me know if it is possible ?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Unicode specification](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) you should be able to use the `EEEEEE` (six E) format to get a two-letter weekday symbol.

Comment: Tried but not working.     formatter.dateFormat = @"EEEEEE";
    NSArray *array = formatter.shortWeekdaySymbols;
Let me know how I can get exact ?

Comment: You don't use `shortWeekdaySymbols`. That's not affected by the date format. You format an `NSDate` object with the date formatter to get the weekday string.

Answer (score 2):

As rmaddy has mentioned, you can use six E format. That will give you Mo, Tu, We etc. But if you want them in captitals specifically (MO, TU, WE, etc), you can set the `veryShortWeekdaySymbols` property of the `NSDateFormatter` object and use the same format mentioned in the question. You can use any Weekday Symbol you wish. As follows:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.veryShortWeekdaySymbols = @[@"SU", @"MO", @"TU", @"WE", @"TH", @"FR", @"SA"];
formatter.dateFormat = @"EEEEE";
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: People using languages other than English won't care for this solution.

Comment: @Shanti I have tried rmaddy solution but i am getting S,M,T,W,T,F,S with veryShortWeekdaySymbols and six E. I should be able to easily use capitalizedString. Can you please help me why i am not getting two letters ?